Best way to get spring boot feign response headers
I have a spring boot 3.x.x application and I am using feign client.
Feign client response structure is as follows
@PostMapping("${path}")
BaseResponse<Object> post(Request request);

In the above way, I can only get the response body.
@PostMapping("${path}")
Response post(Request request);

By using the Feign response class, I can take the entire response and distinguish the body and headers information in it, but I don't like this very much. I only need response_headers information in some of my requests.
I also get a response header by intervening with the Feign decoder, but it is not a sufficient solution as I have to return by adding the headers I got there to the response body.
Are there any alternative solutions?
